# What does the ! (exclamation mark) mean before selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, jquery-selectors

I know already that the `!` is used generally to express negation like `no`, `not`, and `null` in JavaScript.

But what does the exclamation mark mean before a selector in jQuery?

```
if(!$('selector').hasClass('something')){do something}
```

Comment: It does the same thing.

Comment: It's not before the selector. It's before the expression `$('selector').hasClass('something')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It negates a boolean.

Meaning:

> true becomes false

and

> false becomes true

---

In this example it means:

```
if(!$('selector').hasClass('something'))
```

> if `selector` has **not** class something

The exclamation mark does not apply on the jQuery selector but on the result of the `hasClass` function. It is like you have used brackets (but you don't have to use brackets, JavaScript knows that this is meant).

```
!( $('selector').hasClass('something') /* e.g. returns true */ ) /* now it's false */
```

Answer (score 1):

It simply means `if NOT` then do something so it works opposite to the usual `if` condition.

For example, the **below are same** :

```
if(true) { //or if(something == true)
   //Do something
}

if(!false) { //or if(something != false)
   //Do something
}
```

So in your case, if your selector returns `false` then do something.

Answer (score 0):

is also means the same negation meaning, but you can also use

```
if($('selector.something').length){do something}
```

because in jquery if it do not found elements its length is 0;

also in some situation you can use

```
$('select(:not(:attributor)')
```

for example

```
$('option(:not(:selected))')
```

is the same as

```
!$('option:selected')
```

might this can help you!